# Question in Reinforced Design Course - One Way Slab ACI code

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

Establish the thickness of the floor slab shown of figure below (for section 2B1-
2B2-2B1) for a service live load of 4.8 kN/m2
. Use f'c = 25 MPa, fy = 400 MPa, and
ACI code. Show all your step-by-step calculations for the maximum moment
coefficient and other coefficients within your Excel sheet. Draw the reinforcement
along the section B-B.[image]

Comment: This is not a homework answering service. What is your specific problem & tell us your thinking & show some effort in trying to answer this problem.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post